# Custom circle button for tab navigator no showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm attempting to create a custom circle button like this:
[image]

I accomplished to make the navigation bar, although this middle circle button in which I'm attempting to add to the middle nav is not showing at all. I inserted a red background to see if is was going to show. If I click in the middle position, it is working fine, it goes into the page
My result:

[image]

The button style:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Circle } from './styles';

export function TabBarCircle({ children, onPress }: any) {
  return (
    <Container onPress={onPress}>
      <Circle>{children}</Circle>
    </Container>
  );
}

-------------------- styled component -------------------
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';

export const Container = styled.TouchableOpacity``;

export const Circle = styled.View`
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: ${RFValue(40)}px;
  height: ${RFValue(40)}px;
  background-color: 'red';
  border-radius: ${RFValue(20)}px;
`;
```

The tab bar part:

```
  <Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.primary,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          borderTopRightRadius: 16,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 16,
          borderColor: '#9E9E9E',
          borderWidth: 1.5,
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          bottom: 0,
          height: 90,
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Screen
        key="Home"
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Home" focused={focused} icon="Home" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="Search"
        name="Search"
        component={Search}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Search" focused={focused} icon="Search" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="CreatePost"
        name="CreatePost"
        component={CreatePost}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <PlusSVG width={10} height={10} />,
          tabBarButton: (props) => <TabBarCircle {...props} fill="red" />,
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="Shorts"
        name="Shorts"
        component={Shorts}
```

Comment: Sometimes the navigation messes up, have you tried restarting yet? I don't see anything in the Screen element that looks wrong. What happens if you replace  tabBarIcon with a different component?

Comment: If I replace with another component it works, I think is the way I built the View or something

Comment: The issue seems to be with `styled-components` I used normal View inside route and it worked